# end='' SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python-3.x, syntax-error

Help! `end=''` is causing a syntax error and I'm not sure why.

```
def print_game_board(game_board_marker):
    for i in range(len(game_board_marker)):
        for j in range(len(game_board_marker[i])):
            print(str(game_board_marker[i][j]).rjust(4), end='')
        print()
    print()
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you're using Python 2.x, not 3.x.

Check your python version:

```
$ python -V
```

---

Python 2.7:

```
>>> print(1, end='')
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print(1, end='')
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Python 3.3:

```
>>> print(1, end='')
1>>>
```